# Hiding the logs of an API call

Tags: java, spring-boot, thorntail

I am making an http request using Httpclient and I need to hide logs for this specific API call as it contains sensitive data. We need the logs to be in debug level so lowering the log level is not an option is there a way that I can hide the logs of just this request?

```
public Boolean authenticate(String userName, String password) throws IOException {
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(authServiceBaseUrl + AUTH_SERVICE_AUTH_URI);
   try {
        StringEntity httpEntity = new StringEntity(new JSONObject()
            .put(USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, userName)
            .put(PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, password)
            .toString());
        httpEntity.setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(logException(userName, "authenticate"), e );
      }

      try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
       CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) {
       if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
           return Boolean.TRUE;
       } else if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
           log.warnf("[%s] Authentication failed.", userName);
           return Boolean.FALSE;
       } else {
           throw new UserAuthenticationException(
               response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), userName,
               "Error while trying to authenticate user");
       }
   } catch (UserAuthenticationException e) {
     throw e;
   } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new Exception(logException(userName, "authenticate"), e);
   }
 }
```

Comment: What does "hide the logs" mean?  It sounds like just removing the logging calls is not an option?

Comment: Anyway that I can make it so that the logs of the API call does not show the data. Whether it means masking the data somehow or removing the logging entirely for just that specific call.

Comment: So then remove the logging calls from your code?  Is that sufficient?

Comment: `ESC[0mESC[32m2021-11-21 15:17:55,265 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-3257) http-outgoing-18251` as far as I know there is no specific logging for this API call so I assumed that the logging automatically happens for any call using httpClient correct me if I am wrong. If so how do I remove the logging calls?